# What is the name of this iOS view?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, ios8

I want to reproduce in my iOS 8 app the same kind of native view captured below.

What is the name of this "scroll multi-select" view? Where can I find the documentation to instantiate this type of view in my app?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be a [UIPickerView](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerView_Class/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

UIPickerView.

But superjacent View should be a diy view.

you can create a new class inherit UIView or UIPickerView,then,  Add your custom headerView.

Change PickerView Styles for yourself.

Thanks.